# HTML <span> carryover onto next text

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```html
<div>
      Action: 
      <span style="text-decoration: underline"> write<span>
      <span style="text-decoration: none">(disabled)<span>
</div>
```

The **"(disabled)"** word is underlined even after I explicitly put ***style="text-decoration: none"***.

Why is that happening and how can I remove underlining of the **"(disabled)"**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't close your first `span` tag

```html
<div>
  Action: 
  <span style="text-decoration: underline"> write</span>
  <span style="text-decoration: none">(disabled)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Or the second `span` tag..

Comment: **And** the second `span` tag.